# Cordova Geolocalização

Tags: apache-cordova, ionic, geolocalização

Estou tendo um problema muito estranho, tenho um app rodando a um ano e depois de uns meses sem atualizações ao fazer uma nova release percebi que a geolocalização não estava funcionando corretamente. Quando utilizo a função getCurrentPosition não da erro, porém o objeto retornado é vazio. Fiz um app novo só para testar e o mesmo problema ocorreu. **Estou testando com Ionic**.

Preciso de uma solução urgente. Houve alguma atualização na forma de implementar isso recentemente?

Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Como podem ver nesse exemplo básico eu queria apenas ver as
>   informações retornadas, mas por algum motivo que eu desconheço não da
>   erro porém o objeto está vazio.

Answer (score 2):

Não está retornando nada, porque você colocou dentro do

```
if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard)
```

Coloque **fora do if**, sua função:

```js
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(res) {
      console.log("deu certo...");
      console.log(JSON.stringify(res.coords));
    }, function(err) {
      console.log("deu erro...");
      console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    })

    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

Espero que tenha te ajudado!

**Abraços!**

Answer (score 0):

Tenta dessa forma:

```
    var positionOptions = {maximumAge:0, timeout: 30000, enableHighAccuracy: true};

    function gpsSuccess(obj){
      console.log('GPS Success latitude: ' + obj.coords.latitude);
      console.log('GPS Success longitude: ' + obj.coords.longitude);
    }

    function gpsError(obj){
      console.log('Gps error' + JSON.stringify(obj));
    }

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(gpsSuccess, gpsError, positionOptions);
```

Comment: Cara seu código funciona, mas me explica uma coisa, porque seu código funciona e o código abaixo não:

[Código no Pastie.org](http://pastie.org/private/vwkmkwhjwuqcbytj3gs1hw)